# Combine two different size tables adding their elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two tables with diferent sizes which *"represents"* two discrete functions.

`table1 = {{3, 5}, {13, 15}}`
[image]
`table2 = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}}`
[image]
I need to obtain this result:
`result = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 0, 14, 0, 15}}`
[image]

The result is the sum of the two "functions" with using the "domain" of the second.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = KeyValueMap[List] @ KeySort @ Merge[Total][AssociationThread @@@ #] &;

f[{table1, table2}] // TableForm
```

[image]

Also

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2 = Sort @ KeyValueMap[List] @ Merge[Total][AssociationThread @@@ #] &;

f2[{table1, table2}] // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
table1 = {{3, 5}, {13, 15}};
table2 = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}};

Flatten[{table1, table2}, {3, 1}]  (*Out: {{3, 13}, {1, 1}, {5, 15}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}}*)
GroupBy[%, First -> Last, Total]   (*Out: <|3 -> 14, 1 -> 1, 5 -> 15, 2 -> 0, 4 -> 0|>*)
Normal[%] /. Rule -> List // Sort  (*Out: {{1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 14}, {4, 0}, {5, 15}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am sure there is a better way and with less code to do this may be using smart threading or some other one Mathematica cool command, but I am lazy to look for it now, so here is a quick hack

```
Clear["Global`*"];
table1 = Transpose[{{3, 5}, {13, 15}}];
table2 = Transpose[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}}];
max = Max[table1[[All, 1]], table2[[All, 1]]];
min = Min[table1[[All, 1]], table2[[All, 1]]];
range = Range[min, max];
fixTable1 = If[MemberQ[table1[[All, 1]], #], 
     First@Extract[table1, Position[table1[[All, 1]], #]], {0, 0}] & /@range;
fixTable2 = If[MemberQ[table2[[All, 1]], #], 
     First@Extract[table2, Position[table2[[All, 1]], #]], {0, 0}] & /@range;
fixed = Transpose[{range, fixTable1[[All, 2]] + fixTable2[[All, 2]]}];
TableForm[fixed, TableHeadings -> {None, {"x", "y"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]